# Angular Router error redirecting to path with dynamic parameter

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I want to redirect user to a path with a unique UUID when they hit root (`localhost:4200`).

But I get this error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'document/4fdb309b-df59-4da8-a32d-5265f7925bba'
>
> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'document/4fdb309b-df59-4da8-a32d-5265f7925bba'

Below is my router module code segment

```js
import { v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid'

const routes : Routes = [
  {path : '', redirectTo : '/document/'+uuidv4(), pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path : 'documents/:id', component: DocumentComponent}
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Not sure whats wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably it's due to route ordering. Try to rearrange the routes

```js
const routes : Routes = [
  {path : 'documents/:id', component: DocumentComponent},
  {path : '', redirectTo : '/document/'+uuidv4(), pathMatch: 'full'}
]
```

Note that Angular Router uses [first-match wins strategy](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-order) and the ordering of the routes in the array does matter.

Comment: Yep, That was it, working fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not declare dynamic route path. uuid4() will generate different uuid every time and you don't have those many components mapped to routes. you may want uuid as a route parameter as well. change first route to following and see if it helps.

```
{path : '', redirectTo : '/document/someComponent', pathMatch: 'full'},
```

Comment: That didn't help, got same error. I want to generate new ID and redirect user to same component everytime. Is there any alternate approach.

Comment: If you are redirecting to same component then why not give static path? Check my edit.